# How to refresh ng-repeat table in AngularJS onclick button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can not update the value of the fields in the table with ng-repeat in any way onclick of a JS function, not even with a $ scope.apply () or with a timeout.
This is my HTML Code :

```
<div class="container">
   <table class="table" id="table">
      <thead class="table-bordered">
         <th ng-repeat="(column_name,v) in response[0];">{{column_name}}<br>
            <b>Class:</b>
            <a ng-click="chooseClass(column_name)"  id="{{column_name + 1}}">
            {{kls_dict[column_name][0]}}
            </a>
            <br>
            <b>Transfs:</b>
            <a ng-click="chooseTrf(column_name)" id="{{column_name + 2}}">
            {{kls_transfs[kls_dict[column_name][0]][0]}}
            </a>
         </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="row in response">
            <td ng-repeat="value in row">{{value}}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

And this is my JS function called in another HTML button component :

```
$scope.save_params = function (old_transformation, object) {

    console.log("Enter save_params");
    console.log("trfs", old_transformation)
    console.log(object)
    console.log('class', $rootScope.old_class)
    console.log('columns_name', $rootScope.show_column_name)
    to_send = {
        'class': $rootScope.old_class,
        'column_name': $rootScope.show_column_name,
        "trfs": old_transformation,
        "params": object
    }
    $rootScope.spm.close();
    $http({
        url: "/send_parameters",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data: JSON.stringify(to_send)
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }).error(function () {
        console.error('Errore durante invio dei parametri');
        $("#warning-alert").text("Errore durante l'invio dei parametri, riprovare o controllare i parametri specificati");
        $("#warning-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
            $("#warning-alert").slideUp(500);
        });
    });
};
```

I have already specify the AngularJS controller. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Where are you consuming **$scope.save_params** function in template?

Comment: In another html file :          <button ng-click="save_params(old_transformation, object)" id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">OK

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: Nope, and also i see in console the correct output what i'm expecting to see in the refreshed ng-repeat table

Comment: Why you are not updating **$scope.response** after successful update of the record in **$scope.save_params** function? or do you have separate rest call to get the updated list to update **$scope.response** in different controller?

Comment: I have added in .success a new assign of $scope.response but there is no changes in refresh trouble...